# Drawing a game board programmatically

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, image

Trying to draw a simple 15x15 game board onto an iPad.

Currently my code is printing just one image in the upper left, which seems to potentially be the final image added to the imgViewArray but not 100% certain.

```
func createImgBoard() {
    let cellWidth = 57
    let cellHeight = 57
    let squares = 225

    var k = 0
    var row = 0; var col = 0

    let topY = 500-4*cellHeight
    let leftX = 384-4*cellWidth

    var image: UIImage

    for i in 0...14 {
        for j in 0...14 {
            if board[i][j].symbol == "*" {
                image = UIImage(named: "grass57x57px")!
                imgViewArray[k].image = image
            }
            else {
                image = UIImage(named: "notgrass57x57px")!
                imgViewArray[k].image = image
            }
            k+=1
            print("Added img to imgViewArray " + String(k) + " as " + String(describing: image))
        }
    }

    for i in 0...squares-1 {

        imgViewArray[i].frame = CGRect.init(x: leftX+cellWidth*col, y: topY+cellHeight*row, width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight)

        self.view.addSubview(imgViewArray[i])

        col+=1
        if col > 14 {
            row+=1
            col=0
        }

    } 
}
```

EDIT: For some reason now it is not even showing the single image, even though the code hasn't changed at all...

Comment: Use your debugger. Step through the code and check the values of your variables and see where things go wrong.

Comment: But `row+=row` should probably be `row += 1`.

Comment: Why you are not use collection view? Use section and item for it and save state in image model.

Answer (score 0):

Why even use two separate loops? You can do everything you need in the first (nested) loops.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    let board: [[String]] = []
    let cellImageView: [[UIImageView]] = []

    func createBoardImageViews() {
        let cellWidth = 57
        let cellHeight = 57
        let boardWidth = 15
        let boardHeight = 15

        let x0 = 384 - 4 * cellWidth
        let y0 = 500 - 4 * cellHeight

        let imageForCellMarker: [String: UIImage] = [
            "*": UIImage(named: "grass")!,
            // etc., assuming you have other cell marker types
        ]
        let defaultCellImage = UIImage(named: "notgrass")!

        for y in 0 ..< boardHeight {
            cellImageView.append([])
            for x in 0 ..< boardWidth {
                let image = imageForCellMarker[board[y][x]] ?? defaultCellImage
                let frame = CGRect(x: x0 + x * cellWidth, y: y0 + y * cellHeight, width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight)
                let imageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
                imageView.image = image
                cellImageView[y].append(imageView)
                view.addSubview(imageView)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Just tried this code exactly, only changing the image file names to my ones, but still just blank on the iPad :/

Comment: The `x0` and `y0` values seem fishy to me but I copied them from your code. Try setting them to zero. What do you see in the view debugger?

Comment: A friend is doing the exact same thing but on an iPhone and your code works perfectly for his, but just blank on my iPad version :/ no idea what is going on.

Comment: If I've solved your problem, please click the check mark next to my answer.